# Save datagridview dynamically filled in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, dynamic, datagridview

I'm searchin for a way to solve my problem, in relation with a previous question.

I have to manage different payment methods in Datagridview.

An user (cashier for example) have to check all money they have at the end of their service.

In a parent form, i display payment methods names, automatically amounts from an other database, two empty columns and a column with buttons "details".

Initially the datagridview in parent form looks like this :

```
PAYMENT      |   QTY   |  AUTOMATIC  |  MANUAL  |  DIFF.   |  DETAILS  |
_____________|_________|_____________|__________|__________|___________|
CREDIT CARD  |   2     |    46.80    |          |          | [DETAILS] |
CHECK        |   1     |    25.65    |          |          | [DETAILS] |
BANK TRANSFER|   1     |   150.25    |          |          | [DETAILS] |
```

When the user click on a details button, i display a child form with an other datagridview with details of a payment method. I load the form like this in the parent form :

```
var details = new FrmDetails("FormName", "IdOfPaymentMethod");
details.ShowDialog();
```

For the credit card for example, i get a datagridview in the child form like this :

```
  DATE/HOUR          | TICKET NUMBER |  AMOUNT  |  CHECK  |
_____________________|_______________|__________|_________|
 01/11/2015 - 08:23  |   138170      |  12.90   |         |
 01/11/2015 - 09:45  |   138191      |  33.90   |    v    |
```

These are the two payments by credit card for the date that user has selected beforehand. The sum of both is what you can see in the column "AUTOMATIC" in parent form. The last column "CHECK" contains checkboxes, users checks if they have the payment with them.

In my example, user check only the second line with 33.90 and not the other one.
When they close this details form, the parent datagridview update like this :

```
    PAYMENT      |   QTY   |  AUTOMATIC  |  MANUAL  |  DIFF.   |  DETAILS  |
    _____________|_________|_____________|__________|__________|___________|
    CREDIT CARD  |   2     |    46.80    |  33.90   | -12.90   | [DETAILS] |
    CHECK        |   1     |    25.65    |          |          | [DETAILS] |
    BANK TRANSFER|   1     |   150.25    |          |          | [DETAILS] |
```

This is the simple operation of the application.
The problem is that I have to save each datagridview "details" in a SQL database (SQL Server). The user has to enter other information before these payments so the solution that I thought was to save the previous datas in a table "ENTRIES" then retrieve the ID max, and save each datagridview "details" with a link ID_ENTRY as a foreign key.
I can do that with a single datagridview "details" but i lose all the check/uncheck when i press on others details button on the parent form.

Is there a way to keep each datagridview "details" until the final recording?

I hope my message was clear and comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of each instance of `FrmDetails` is only the scope of the button's click event - hence the data is gone.

- Either you'll have to keep around a collection of `FrmDetails` instances for each payment method row:

  ```
  var details = new List<FrmDetails>();

  foreach (var row in dataGridView1.Rows)
  {
      var detail = new FrmDetails("FormName", "IdOfPaymentMethod");
      details.Add(detail);
  }

  // And when clicking on a Details button:
  details[e.ColumnIndex].ShowDialog();
  ```
- Or a collection of their equivalent data (I used `List` here, but I'd recommend something bindable - pending your source code):

  ```
  var detailsData = new List<DetailsDataSources>();

  foreach (var row in dataGridView1.Rows)
  {
      var details = GetThisRowsDetails();
      detailsData.Add(details);
  }

  // And when clicking on a Details button, somehow set the DataSource:
  var details = new FrmDetails("FormName");
  details.childDataGridView1.DataSource = detailsData[e.ColumnIndex];
  details.ShowDialog();
  /*
   * Ensure the changes made in the details form are then afterwards
   * reflected in detailsData[e.ColumnIndex]
   */
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already found a solution but yours is quite similar to mine. I created a table of datagridview, I access with e.RowIndex to know on which payment method I am. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'm glad to help, even if it's just to confirm what you already discovered. :)